# Throw a warning in WiX

Tags: .net, wix

I am running into a complex situation where I have two install packages. One depends on the install of the other. And uninstall must be done in the correct order as well.

I am having a lot of trouble getting the conditions to work to prevent one from being uninstalled if the other is still installed. I keep making conditions that prevent uninstall no matter what - which is very messy to clean up...

So all I want now is to raise a warning message when a condition is met. Something like "Warning: You should uninstall X before you uninstall this package" with Quit and Ignore buttons. Is there any way to make a conditional warning in WiX 3?

Comment: If the applications are that tightly coupled it actually sounds like a single application? In most cases I advocate splitting applications into separate files for easier maintenance and future flexibility, but if the coupling is as strong as you describe it really seems like it's better delivered as a single package. A quick and dirty solution could be to make one of the setups a system setup (hidden from add/remove programs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367750(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I need these to be separate installers. Where one can be installed without the other. But the other depends on the first. And they cannot be a single installer for licensing reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if one (product A) is a prerequisite for the other (B)?

If so, possibly the best way would be to prevent installation of B if A is missing (no "ignore" option). To do that:

- decide how can you verify that A exists (i.e. specific entry in registry created by this installer: as you build it you may add it as one of components)
- add <Property> with appropriate search to it (i.e. RegistrySearch)
- add <Condition> to <Product>

An example could be found i.e. here: http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg31789.html

Additionally, you could create a bootstrapper for B that installs A as prerequisite (thus making it easier for end users).

If the "ignore" option is really a must, I would create a new dialog with the text + buttons, and add it to the setup sequence. But I wouldn't recommend this option, it doesn't support scenario of silent installation.

There is also an alternative - new feature in Windows Installer 4.5, a multiple-package installation. However I have never used that. It also forces users of your software to have Windows Installer 4.5 or later (always in Windows only since Vista SP2).